# Will enabling non-delivery notifications cause more spam?

Tags: email, windows-server-2003, email-server, spam, email-bounces

In the past we received a lot of spam email. The past year it was a lot less and we would like to keep it that way offcourse.

We are a construction company and we receive a lot of construction drawings which are big in filesize. The maximum attachment size we can receive is set at 25 MB.

Now we are facing the issue that there are still people which send us emails with attachments larger than 25 MB. Our server administrator has disabled non-delivery notifications on the server. He told me that enabling it would cause a lot of spam again.

So my question is; Is it true that enabling non-delivery notifications will cause more spam? And if we decide to enable it, what can we do to prevent that spam?

Comment: It seems you should accept larger attachments.

Comment: What @MichaelHampton said. I also work with some architects and real estate colleagues and they often require to send mails with attachments >100 MB. I'm not saying that sending such large mails is the best solution, but _new_ solutions would require clients and partners to adapt, which is sometimes...you know. So, for the time being, I accept huge attachments.

Comment: IT should work in concert with and for the benefit of the business. This attachment size setting is a hindrance to the business.

Comment: I suggested that either to increase the size even more, but he said that that storage will quickly run out of space.